# Integral using Cauchy Schwarz inequality

Tags: vector-analysis, greens-theorem

I'm trying to show that $$\int_a^b \left\|\frac{d\mathbf{r}(t)}{dt} \right\| \ dt = \|\mathbf{r}(b)-\mathbf{r}(a) \| $$ but I'm unsure of how to deal with the integral and the derivative of $\mathbf{r} $. 
Here $\mathbf{r} : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ is a vector valued function of t.

Comment: Is it $=$ or $\ge$?

Comment: This is not true unless $r$ traces out the line segment. All you can really say in general is the left side is $\geq$ the right side.

Comment: It is true that $\int_a^{b}\frac{d\mathbf{r}(t)}{dt}\,dt = \mathbf r(a)-\mathbf r(b)$, but your statement isn't true.

Comment: No, it definitely should be $\geq$.